# Updating $scope in timer loop, template not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to re-retrieve data from a rest service in a simple polling loop. I'm getting the update to occur but the data change is not reflected on my page.  Below is my code snippet

```
function HomeController ($scope,CodeCampYear) {
  $scope.faqs = faqs;

  $scope.value = 0;
  function pollData () {
        CodeCampYear.fetchAll().then(function(data){
            $scope.value += 1;
            $scope.codecampyear = data[0];
            $scope.codecampyear.liveFeedTitle = $scope.value;
        });
    setTimeout(pollData, 1000 * 5)
  }
  pollData();
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) in order to do an `$apply`:

```
function HomeController ($scope,CodeCampYear, $timeout) {
  $scope.faqs = faqs;

  $scope.value = 0;
  function pollData () {
        CodeCampYear.fetchAll().then(function(data){
            $scope.value += 1;
            $scope.codecampyear = data[0];
            $scope.codecampyear.liveFeedTitle = $scope.value;
        });
    $timeout(pollData, 1000 * 5)
  }
  pollData();
  ...
```

Using `$timeout` will allow Angular to enter a digest loop and update the data once the `setTimeout` loop is triggered (the second update).